# Make "Ask an Expert" real

Tags: feature-request

t's actually a good monetizing idea. Make it possible to sign up as an expert (on your tag badges, one would presume) with available hours, set an hourly fee (billed in 15 minutes increments), SE takes a cut and let the "Ask an expert" commence.

Edit: so many downvotes, so quick! Why?

Comment: It's called the "Ask Question" button...

Comment: Ask a Question is not the same as chat, by far.

Comment: You're right, [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/) is pretty awesome...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Stack Exchange sites already have [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/). If you're working  in a popular area (C++, C#, PHP, JavaScript, for instance) and approach the chat participants well, you'll get great results. That's because SE crafted a pretty good formula to entice folks to help - no reward necessary, other than [unicorn dollars](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/03/a-new-name-for-stack-overflow-with-surprise-ending/).

Bring money into the mix? You'll likely mess things up. The studies here are a bit controversial, but look into intrinsic and extrinsic motivation. External rewards can have a corrosive effect on the effort you get when those rewards aren't offered.